# Overriding difficult view model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I am trying to replace some text in an input field using JS but the view model overrides my commands each time. This is the HTML I start with:

```
<td class="new-variants-table__cell" define="{ editVariantPrice: new Shopify.EditVariantPrice(this) }" context="editVariantPrice" style="height: auto;">
    <input type="hidden" name="product[variants][][price]" id="product_variants__price" value="25.00" bind="price" data-dirty-trigger="true">
    <input class="mock-edit-on-hover tr js-no-dirty js-variant-price variant-table-input--numeric" bind-event-focus="onFocus(this)" bind-event-blur="onBlur(this)" bind-event-input="onInput(this)">
</td>
```

I run this JS:

```
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().removeAttr('bind-event-focus');
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().removeAttr('bind-event-input');
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().removeAttr('bind-event-blur');
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().focus()
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().val("34.00");
jQuery('#product_variants__price').val("34.00");
```

And I'm left with the following HTML:

```
<td class="new-variants-table__cell" define="{ editVariantPrice: new Shopify.EditVariantPrice(this) }" context="editVariantPrice" style="height: auto;">
    <input type="hidden" name="product[variants][][price]" id="product_variants__price" value="34.00" bind="price" data-dirty-trigger="true">
    <input class="mock-edit-on-hover tr js-no-dirty js-variant-price variant-table-input--numeric">
</td>
```

The problem is that each time I click the input field the value is reverted to what it was when the page loaded.

I've also tried running the command in the parent td along with my value change, to simulate the editing of a variant and preventing default with no success:

```
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().bind('input', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().bind('focus', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().focus()
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().val("£34.00");
jQuery('#product_variants__price').val("£34.00");
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().keydown()
```

Parent td function:

```
new Shopify.EditVariantPrice(jQuery('#product_variants__price').parent())
```

**So how can I successfully edit this value in the inputs and also update the Shopify view model?**

You can try this for yourself by going here:

> https://jebus333.myshopify.com/admin/products/2521183043
>
> login jebus333@mailinator.com
>   password shop1

EDIT: I've tried to find the view model on the page but with no success. Plus, there are no network calls when editing the values in the input fields, leading me to believe the values are being pulled back from somewhere on page.

Comment: Wow, you have time typing all those `jQuery(...)`s? Why not `$(...)`? They are the same thing!

Comment: I can't remember why I did it like that. It was probably because I was working on another site on which $ referred to the Chrome Command Line API but I can see on Spotify's web site it does indeed refer to jQuery.

Comment: `bind` was pretty much deprecated in JQ 1.7.

Comment: @forgetso use "stopImmediatePropagation()" and " stopPropagation()" and check

Comment: @yugi could you expand on this method? I've tried both methods but not had any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var old = Shopify.EditVariantPrice.prototype.onFocus;
Shopify.EditVariantPrice.prototype.onFocus = function(t) { 
  this.price = '50.00'; // Use the price you want here
  old.call(this, t); 
};
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().triggerHandler("focus");
jQuery('#product_variants__price').siblings().triggerHandler("blur");
```

If it works for you, it's possible that the following will be sufficient:

```
Shopify.EditVariantPrice.prototype.onFocus = function(t) { 
  this.price = '50.00'; // Use the price you want here
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not achieve the result I was after using `string.replace` but it does achieve the desired result without the need for additional libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a kind of a dirty solution...

First of all you'll need a [sendkeys](http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/) plugin. In fact that means you'll need to include [this](https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange/blob/master/bililiteRange.js) and [this](https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange/blob/master/jquery.sendkeys.js) JS libraries (you can just copy-paste them in the console to test). If you don't want to use the first library (I personally find it quite big for such a small thing) you can extract only the key things out of it and use only them.

The next step is creating the function which is going to act like a real user:

```
function input(field, desiredValue) {
  // get the currency symbol while value is still pristine
  var currency = field.val()[0];

  // move focus to the input
  field.click().focus();

  // remove all symbols from the input. I took 10, but of course you can use value.length instead
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) field.sendkeys("{backspace}");

  // send the currency key
  field.sendkeys(currency);

  // send the desired value symbol-by-symbol
  for (var i = 0; i < desiredValue.length; i++) field.sendkeys(desiredValue[i]);
}
```

Then you can simply call it with the value you wish to assign:

```
input($("#product_variants__price").next(), "123.00");
```

I did not really manage to fake the blur event because of lack of the time; that is why I was forced to read the currency and pass `.00` as a string. Anyway you already have a way to go and a quite working solution.

Comment: Thanks. I will add this methodology to my code and report back if it works. If it does, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @forgetso did it work for you? Did you experience problems?

Comment: It does work however it's not going to work in the context of what I'm doing. Can you think of anyway to achieve the same result without using sendkeys? For context, I am trying to search for a user defined string and replace occurrences of the string. With sendkeys I would need to break the search string down into it's individual parts and then send each part. I'd rather do a simple `string.replace`...

Comment: Well if you work with this system you will be forced to play this system's rules. Making replace won't help you because the model won't be updated. Sending the keys is the way which works for any system because this is exactly what user usually does. Everything is already wrapped inside of the function so you don't need to split it again and again, this is what the browser will do. Again, as long as you cannot change the model, imitating the user actions is the only way to deal with all that things

Comment: I disagree with the method. The view model has to be *somewhere* on the page, which means it is editable by string replace. Is this correct? Thank you for explaining that the send keys library handles the entire string so that it doesn't need to be broken down. I had not realised this.

Comment: Well you are free to try many things, and, honestly, I will be happy if you find a better method and I wish you had it. But unfortunately I feel this is the only way you can do.

Comment: I accepted the method that does not include additional libraries. It is still not using `string.replace` but it achieves the desired result with the minimum amount of code. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to automate editing of variant prices of products in Shopify's admin panel.

Instead of playing around with the DOM of Shopify's admin page, I'll suggest using Shopify's bulk product editor which lets you set prices of all variants in a single screen. I feel that you'll have better luck setting the variant prices using JavaScript on the bulk product editor page.

Clicking on the 'Edit Products' button as shown in the screenshot below will open the bulk product editor.

[image: Click on 'Edit Products' to open the bulk product editor.]

Also check if browser based macro recording plugins like [iMacro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) can be of your help (you can also code macros with JS in iMacro).

Comment: Thanks, for context I am working from a Chrome extension and I am searching for a string and trying to replace it within the context of the tab. Programming additional steps to visit the bulk product editor is out of scope.